GNUCobol 3.2.0 Copybooks
I am working with GNUCobol cobc version 3.2.0
It seems that COPYBOOKS do not work during the compile step?  The source code is going through the esqlOC precompiler first. I have these to lines
  COPY RCDC00   
  COPY screenio.cpy

in my source code and neither copybook is found
I have both COBCPY and COB_COPY_DIR environment variables set in my _make.bat file
SET drv=C:
SET apphome=%drv%\EOS
  SET "COB_COPY_DIR=%apphome%\cobcpy"
  SET "COBCPY=%apphome%\cobcpy"

I've tried with and without double quotes. I've even tried putting my copybook names in the environment variable like this
SET "COB_COPY_DIR=%apphome%\cobcpy\RCDC00.cpy"
SET "COBCPY=%apphome%\cobcpy\RCDC00.cpy"
I tried putting the full path inside my cobol program at column 8 as
COPY C:\EOS\cobcpy\RCDC00.cpy
  COPY C:\EOS\cobcpy\RCDC00.cpy.

 COPY "C:\EOS\cobcpy\RCDC00.cpy"

I am familiar with Microfocus and so, I might be blinded to GNUCobol syntax?

These are good questions but they are questions which does not match this site's Q+A style (1 question, 1 or more answers to that). Please have a look at the tour to know how this site works.
... and you cannot switch "NATIONAL" (utf16) to DISPLAY 9 (an ASCII digit).

Do I have the ability to remove my post and submit one question at a time?  I think there was a box that required me to enter what I had done to solve my problem(s)?

Just "edit" your question leaving only some introduction to the issue, then what you want to achieve and what you've tried (related to sqlserver + gnucobol) and create a new question for each other issue.

Today, I got the Cobol COPY statement to work.  Here are my "lessons-learned":


cobc -fixed -v -x -static -I%apphome%\cobcpy -L%apphome%\GNUCobol\lib -o %apphome%\pgmexe\%1.exe %apphome%\source\%1.cob   >>%LOG% 2>&1
 ---MUST have include directory -I%apphome%\cobcpy AFTER -static


COPY must begin in col 12
No quotes
No extension. Will find .cbl, .cob, .cpy
Case does not matter
Copy XXXXXX. Must end with period!
If inside a statement like: IF 1=1 copy xxxx. END-IF.  (remember col 12!)
Copy statements ending with a period will not terminate the outer statement!


please mark this question as answer, making it clear that the question was solved
Can you please recheck the need for col12 and "no quotes"? That may be true for esqloc (not checked) but I have them in col8 all the time since GC 1.1 and still in GC 3.3-dev... Also I do have some examples where quotes are used as well (and the "-static mus be before -I" looks strange as well.
